# Serialize XML to different object

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I have two types of file XML that share some common information but also have some specialization:

```
<Source Alias="Hrc">
   <Variable HandleType="Ext.Poll">
      <Id>ConfiguredTime</Id>
      <Type>Double</Type>
      <SamplingDimension>15</SamplingDimension>
      <MappedData>Main.Section.Child.BaseBoardLoader[1].IS.Reports.Absolute.ConfiguredTime</MappedData>
   </Variable>
</Source>






<Source Alias="Wrt">
   <Variable>
      <Id>Identification.ProductInstanceUri</Id>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <MappedData EfficientAccess="true">
         <RtdbItem>
            <TableName>IDENTIFICATION</TableName>
            <DataName>ProductInstanceU</DataName>
            <Record>0</Record>
         </RtdbItem>        
      </MappedData>
   </Variable>
</Source>
```

In this example *Source* and *Variable* are the same, while *MappedVariable* can be string or object type.
How can I structure classes for automatic serialize XML?

I've create classes with *Paste XML as Classes* function of VisualStudio. But don't help me.

Comment: Just include all the properties from both type in the Variable class.  Some properties may be empty but that should no affect anything.

Comment: The problem is that MappedData sometimes is string sometimes is complex object. I cannot specify a property with same name but different types

Comment: You may need to use a IXmlSerializer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-8.0  What you have posted does not need the IXmlSerializer.  You have 3 properties 1) Attribute EfficientAccess 2) Text 3) Class RtdbItem

Comment: Thank you so much. I set 3 properties as you suggest.